# Private alternative to Thunderbird

Tags: windows, email-client

I am looking for a Windows email client (desktop, nothing cloud based):

***Must have:***

- preferably gratis, but I would pay up to $30 - once; no recurring charges
- *must* fetch email directly to my my PC - no passing through middleman servers
- must support multiple accounts (I currently check 8)
- spell checker (multiple languages)
- good search facilities
- filtering
- HTML email support
- IMAP

***Nice to have***

- unified inbox view
- encryption
- delayed sending (I don't really care if it does not)

For reasons that I won't go into, I am switching away from Thunderbird, so please don't suggest it. I can Google, so would prefer that you recommend something that you use and are happy with.

Comment: Thanks, both (upvote) - question upvoted

Comment: Since IMAP and (presumably full) HTML are must-haves, the client I had in mind when I asked the questions won't meet your need. Should you decide that you can rethink and accept POP3 and less-than-full support for HTML, you might want to look at [Agent by Forté](https://forteinc.com/main/homepage.php).

Comment: I am leaning now towards Claws, as old fashioned as it is. Em client looks good, but I can't find it it uses a middle-main server. I will post an answer if I find something & no one else does.

Answer (score 1):

[EssentialPim](https://www.essentialpim.com) is a commercial email client with other personal information management features (like contacts, events, tasks etc.).

The payed version may be slightly above your budget, currently starting at 36€ for the base version (one time fee, no recurring subscriptions), lifetime upgrades go to 75€. There's also a free version with limitations.

It is privacy focused and [doesn't pipe mail through their private servers](https://essentialpim.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200904551-Why-doesn-t-EPIM-sync-mail-), getting them directly from IMAP server.
It has [spellcheck](https://essentialpim.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204856241-How-do-I-install-additional-spell-checking-dictionaries-) and filtering/searching and tagging.

If you don't mind experimental (at the moment) software there is also [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com). Vivaldi is a web browser in the vein of old Opera from the same creators of the original. It aims to have a built in email client that is at the moment in [technical preview](https://vivaldi.com/blog/vivaldi-mail-technical-preview/) stage of development.

It also has a focus on privacy and data protection and supports filtering and spell checking in all languages Chromium does.

It is not yet ready, but will eventually be released officially.